# Flutter Autocomplete widget causes rebuild loop in Overlay (onSelected not working)

Tags: flutter, dart

When I`m focusing the Autocomplete widget, the parent starts rebuilding and doesn't stop. Nobody seems to have a similar problem.
The Widget used to be split in two Statefull widgets, but for testing it's now one. It seems that it only occurs in overlays, because when I open the Widget with the router, the problem doesn't persist. The bigger problem is, that it is impossible to call onSelected or onChanged.

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:dartz/dartz.dart' hide State;
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';
import 'package:flutter_frontend/domain/my_location/my_location.dart';
import 'package:flutter_frontend/l10n/app_strings.dart';
import 'package:flutter_frontend/presentation/core/style.dart';
import 'package:flutter_frontend/presentation/core/utils/geo/search_completion.dart';
import 'package:flutter_frontend/presentation/pages/core/widgets/Overlays/my_location_form/cubit/my_locations_form_cubit.dart';
import 'package:flutter_frontend/presentation/pages/core/widgets/styling_widgets.dart';
import 'package:flutter_frontend/presentation/pages/core/widgets/stylings/coordinates_picker_with_adress_autocomplete.dart';

import '../../../../../core/utils/geo/osm_extensions/utilities.dart';

class MyLocationFormOverlay {
  MyLocationFormOverlay({MyLocation? myLocation, required BuildContext context}) {
    final OverlayState overlayState = Overlay.of(context)!;
    OverlayEntry? overlayEntry;
    overlayEntry =
        OverlayEntry(builder: (context) => DismissibleOverlay(overlayEntry: overlayEntry!, child: MyLocationForm(location: myLocation,),));
    overlayState.insert(overlayEntry);
  }
}

class MyLocationForm extends StatefulWidget {


  MyLocationForm({Key? key, MyLocation? location}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyLocationForm> createState() => _MyLocationFormState();
}

class _MyLocationFormState extends State<MyLocationForm> {

  // this attribute tells us wheter the address is on cooldown
  bool isCooldown = false;

  // cooldownduration in Milliseconds
  static const int cooldownDuration = 1000;

  Timer? timer;
  List<SearchInfoDetailed> _searchInfoOtions = <SearchInfoDetailed>[];


  static String _displayStringForOption(SearchInfoDetailed option) {

    return option.addressDetailed.toString();
  }

  static GlobalKey _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  final controller_name = TextEditingController();
  final controller_longitude = TextEditingController();
  final controller_latitude = TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BasicContentContainer(
        child_ren: right(
            BlocProvider(
              create: (context) => MyLocationsFormCubit(),
              child: BlocConsumer<MyLocationsFormCubit, MyLocationsFormState>(
                  listenWhen: (p,c) => p.runtimeType != c.runtimeType,
                  listener: (context, state) {
                    if(state is MyLocationFormAdding){
                      controller_name.text = (state as MyLocationFormAdding).location.name.getOrEmptyString();
                      controller_longitude.text = (state as MyLocationFormAdding).location.longitude.toString();
                      controller_latitude.text = (state as MyLocationFormAdding).location.latitude.toString();
                      setState(() {});
                    }
                  },
                  buildWhen: (p, c) => p.runtimeType != c.runtimeType,
                  builder: (context, state) {
                    return Form(
                      key: _formKey,
                      child: Column(
                        children: [
                          Text(AppStrings.addLocation, style: AppTextStyles.stdLittleHeading,),
                          FullWidthPaddingInput(
                            labelText: AppStrings.name,
                            controller: controller_name,
                            hintText: AppStrings.name,
                            onChanged: (value) => _formCubit(context).changeName(value),
                          ),
                          _buildAdressAutocomplete(context),
                          _buildCoordFields(context),
                          //_buildCoordinatesPickerAndAutoCompleteAdress(context)
                        ],
                      ),
                    );
                  }
              ),
            )
        )
    );
  }

  MyLocationsFormCubit _formCubit(BuildContext context) {
    return context.read<MyLocationsFormCubit>();
  }


  // ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  // ----------------------------------------------------------- WIDGETS --------------------------------------------------------------
  // ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  Autocomplete<SearchInfoDetailed> _buildAdressAutocomplete(BuildContext context) {
    print("rebuid");
    return Autocomplete<SearchInfoDetailed>(

      fieldViewBuilder:
          (BuildContext context, TextEditingController fieldTextEditingController, FocusNode fieldFocusNode, VoidCallback onFieldSubmitted) {
        return FullWidthPaddingInput(
          labelText: AppStrings.address,
          hintText: AppStrings.address,
          fieldFocusNode: fieldFocusNode,
          controller: fieldTextEditingController,
        );
      },
      displayStringForOption: _displayStringForOption,
      optionsBuilder: (TextEditingValue textEditingValue) async {
        if(this.isCooldown){
          return _searchInfoOtions;
        }
        // this sets the cooldown
        Timer(Duration(milliseconds: cooldownDuration), () async { this.isCooldown = false; });
        this.isCooldown = true;
        //--------
        // check whether the value is empty
        if (textEditingValue.text == '') {
          return const Iterable<SearchInfoDetailed>.empty();
        }
        // get suggestion
        _searchInfoOtions = await addressSuggestionDetailed(textEditingValue.text);
        //setState( (){});
        return (_searchInfoOtions);
      },
      // set coordinates
      onSelected: (SearchInfoDetailed selection) {
        _formCubit(context).changeAddress(selection.addressDetailed.toString());
         _formCubit(context).changeLatitude(selection.point?.latitude?? 0);
        _formCubit(context).changeLongitude(selection.point?.longitude?? 0);
        // TODO: add only jena here!
        controller_longitude.text = selection.point?.longitude.toString() ?? '';
        controller_latitude.text = selection.point?.latitude.toString() ?? '';
      },

      // we can generate an custom view of the options
    );
  }



  ConstrainedBox _buildCoordFields(BuildContext context) {
    return ConstrainedBox(constraints: BoxConstraints(maxHeight: 56),
      child:

      Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
        children: [
          Flexible(child: CoordinatesPickerInput(
            textEditingControllerLongi: controller_longitude,
            labeltext: "longitude",
            onChanged: (value2) =>
                _formCubit(context).changeLongitude(double.parse(value2 == "" ? '0' : value2)),)),
          Flexible(child: CoordinatesPickerInput(
            textEditingControllerLongi: controller_latitude,
            labeltext: "Latitude",
            onChanged: (value2) => _formCubit(context).changeLatitude(double.parse(value2 == "" ? '0' : value2)),)),
        ],
      ),);
  }
}
```